# How do I get XHR to show responseXML as an HTML element (without innerHTML)

Tags: javascript, xml, dom, xmlhttprequest, appendchild

Related to [turning Ajax Responsexml into HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5682662/turning-ajax-responsexml-into-html)
I'm trying to use XHR to get a `<select>` element with a few options and append them to a `<div>`, but using `importNode()` and `appendChild()` I can't get the response to render as an HTML element. Instead, all that shows is the text of the options.
For example, here's my xml:

```
<select>
    <option value='1'>A</option>
</select>
```

The resulting page only shows the text `A` instead of a `select` element. Why aren't the elements rendered, and what's a good method to properly import them (without innerHTML)?

Fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/9D9pD/2/

Relevant javascript [I even tried `adoptNode()`]:

```
function handleResponse() {
    var xmlResponse = xmlHttp.responseXML,
        root = xmlResponse.documentElement;
    console.log(xmlHttp.responseText);
    var i = document.importNode(root, true);
    var a = document.adoptNode(root);
    document.getElementById("import").appendChild(i);
    document.getElementById("adopt").appendChild(a);
}
```

Comment: I learned some things, thanks http://jsfiddle.net/9D9pD/4/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make use of the DOMParser, which can be pretty usefull in this case. I [updated your fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9D9pD/3/)

```
var parser = new DOMParser()
var el = parser.parseFromString(xmlHttp.responseText, "text/html");
document.getElementById("import").appendChild(el.childNodes[0]);
```

Comment: If you run into problems with some Browsers, see [questions/9500318](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9500318/troubles-trying-to-parse-an-html-string-with-domparser) . I found this to be usefull, because Opera wasn't able to parse into text/html